# How to use the same line of code in all functions?

Tags: python

I am newbie in Python. 
I wonder if it is possible that all functions inherit the same line of code?

`with open(filename, 'r') as f:` as this line of code is the same in all three functions. Is it possible to inherit the code without using classes?

I tried to find the answer on stackoverflow and python documentation, but with no luck.

```
def word_count(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return len(f.read().split())


def line_count(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return len(f.read().splitlines())


def character_count(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return len(f.read())
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The common code in your case is

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

So just move it to its own function:

```
def get_file_contents(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return f.read()

def word_count(filename):
    return len(get_file_contents(filename).split())

def line_count(filename):        
    return len(get_file_contents(filename).splitlines())

def character_count(filename):
    return len(get_file_contents(filename))
```

Comment: I would name the function `contents` instead of `get_file_contents`.

Comment: @PeterWoord The function's name is supposed to describe what it does. I would argue that "contents" does not adequately fulfill this requirement.

Comment: Maybe contents_of? Then it reads more like English but can't be used like a noun (like contents can be). Also, it describes what it does. contents_of_file could be used since Python's dynamic and all that jazz.

Comment: @ZacCrites It can be argued that "get" in a function name is redundant, but it depends on one's position on the functional–imperative paradigm axis. The mathematical function sin is not called "get_sin", after all. An "of" suffix is arguably also redundant as the parentheses are often pronounced "of" - for instance, sin(x) can be pronounced "sin of x".

Comment: Function names prefixed with "get" are only used in antiquated languages that don't support property getters. The sensible thing to do is to make contents a property of a file structure, reading File(name: "whatever").contents. I don't know how close you can get to that with Python. contentsOfFile(with name: String) is a concession if you have to use a global function.

Comment: I personally think that the function name is irrelevant to this question, but here's my rationale. I prefer to use "get_" prefix to mark functions that take a (relatively) considerable time to run and/or whose results is uncertain (like in this case where the function performs I/O). I do not insist on this rule and could be easily persuaded to change the name in any collaborative project.

Comment: @fjarri: That's a neat rule, but I think it should be mentioned only with the huge caveat that if the reader is coming from one of those "antiquated languages" (Jessy's words) that don't support properties, then they will likely understand `x.get_foo()` as the widespread convention for a trivial getter, i.e. exactly the *opposite* of your own convention! This could lead to the reader's misunderstanding the intent of the code. Similar mixups could occur if you later pull in a third-party library where "`get_` means getter" and end up needing to switch between both conventions in the same file.

Answer (score 15):

What I've done in the past is split the code out into another function, in your example

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
         f.read()
```

Is common within all of your methods, so I'd look at rewriting it like so.

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
         return f.read()

def word_count(filename):
    return len(read_file(filename).split())

def line_count(filename):
    return len(read_file(filename).splitlines())

def character_count(filename):
    return len(read_file(filename))
```

Comment: Something like this is definitely what I suggest!

Comment: Depending on the use case, `read_file()` could make use of memoization, so consecutive calls to the `*_count()` functions won't reload the same data again (which is a performance gain)

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria: The accepted answer was posted 18 seconds earlier (you can hover over the "answered X ago" to see the times).

Comment: Why doesn't StackOverflow have a "Mark as duplicate answer" flag or anything like that?

Answer (score 6):

I would use a class:

```
class Count:
    """ Object holds everything count-related """
    def __init__(self, filename):
        """ specify filename in class instance """
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            self.content = f.read()

    def word_count(self):
        return len(self.content.split())

    def line_count(self):
        return len(self.content.splitlines())

    def character_count(self):
        return len(self.content)

file = Count("whatever.txt")
print(file.word_count())
print(file.line_count())
print(file.character_count())
```

Comment: An side since version isn't specified:  If this is python 2, you should inherit from `object`, otherwise you get an old-style object.  In python 3, it doesn't matter

Comment: Note that this is also a solution that doesn't re-read the file for every operation.

Answer (score 3):

What you do differently is after you open the file, so if I were in your shoes, I would write a function which takes another function that is executed after the file is opened.

Let's illustrate this in an example:

```
>>> def operate_file(filename, func):
...     with open(filename, 'r') as f:
...         return func(f)

>>> def line_count(f):
...     return len(f.read().splitlines())

>>> def word_count(f):
...     return len(f.read().split())

>>> def character_count(f):
...     return len(f.read())

>>> print operate_file('/tmp/file.txt', line_count)
1200

>>> print operate_file('/tmp/file.txt', word_count)
2800

>>> print operate_file('/tmp/file.txt', character_count)
29750
```

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to show OP that he could also do something different with the file than reading it.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend decorators. It's sort of like the making the repeated line of code into a function, but since you are going to call that function on each input anyway, decorators can let you just write the functions as id `f` was the input.

The `@open_file` is a shorthand for `word_count=open_file(word_count)`.

[here](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Decorators) is a good place to read more about python decorators.

```
def open_file(func):
    def wrapped_func(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            return func(f)
    return wrapped_func

@open_file
def word_count(f):
    return len(f.read().split())

@open_file
def line_count(f):
    return len(f.read().splitlines())

@open_file
def character_count(f):
    return len(f.read())
```

Comment: With this solution, it would be best to name `f` something clearer, such as `fhandle`.

Comment: In real code yes, but in this example I wanted to keep it consistent. It should be clear the `f` here is the same thing as the `f` in the op's code.

Comment: Oh, I know, but the tricky detail here is that after applying the decorator, `word_count` et al. now take a different type of argument than their original signature would imply. This is why the name of the filehandle becomes much more important when the `with open` line has been moved to a decorator.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on, what you want to do with the results of your 3 functions. Every function is opening the same file. That happens 3 times just to get 3 different properties.
One good solution would be a class. But another would be to rearange your functions to just one. That could return a dictionary or named tuple with the results.

It would look something like this:

```
def file_count(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        properties = {}
        properties['words'] = len(content.split())
        properties['lines'] = len(content.splitlines())
        properties['chars'] = len(content)
        return properties
```